# Can't save list of Pillow images as PDF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a list of PIL ImageFiles in a list called `pages` like this:

```
[<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=612x792 at 0x21DEE7E0AF0>, 
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=612x792 at 0x21DEE7E00A0>, 
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=612x792 at 0x21DEE7E0370>, 
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=612x792 at 0x21DEE7E02B0>, 
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=612x792 at 0x21DEE7E0160>]
```

If I do `pages[0].show()`, I can see the image.

If I do `pages[0].save("test.png")`, that works.

If I do `pages[0].save("test.pdf")`, that works too.

However, I want to save the entire list of images as one PDF where each image is one page.

So I did:
`pages[0].save("test2.pdf", save_all=True, append_images=pages[1:])`

However, this raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\redact\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2134, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\redact\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 41, in _save_all
    _save(im, fp, filename, save_all=True)
  File "C:\Users\redact\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 117, in _save
    for im in im_pages:
  File "C:\Users\redact\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\ImageSequence.py", line 49, in __next__
    self.im.seek(self.position)
  File "C:\Users\redact\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 731, in seek
    if not self._seek_check(frame):
  File "C:\Users\redact\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 296, in _seek_check
    frame < self._min_frame
AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute '_min_frame'
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Python 3.8.5 with Pillow 7.1.2. I also tried the latest PIL version 8.0.1.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1: Calling it without `save_all=True` only saves the first image.

EDIT 2:

I tried making a minimum example like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

random_pixels = np.random.rand(100, 100, 3) * 255
images = [Image.fromarray(random_pixels.astype("uint8")) for i in range(10)]

images[0].save("test.pdf", save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])
```

HOWEVER, this minimum example works for me and saves a PDF with all the random images correctly.

Comment: try without `save_all`., e.g. `pages[0].save("test2.pdf", append_images=pages[1:])`

Comment: That doesn't raise the error, but only saves a PDF with the first page. It's identical to just calling pages[0].save("test.pdf")

Comment: no, it is not. as per the docs `append images` - A list of images to append as additional pages. Each of the images in the list can be single or multiframe images. save_all is only for multiframe images (e..g TIFF)

Comment: Please check this link if it answer's to your question https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2511

Comment: Buran it's true that's what the docs say, but when I call that I get a PDF with a single page even though pages[1:] contains multiple elements.

Comment: Pillow can't save RGBA images to pdf, make sure the image is RGB
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/06/12/batch-convert-images-to-pdf-with-python-using-pillow-or-img2pdf/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the problem with `append_images` argument and **don't know why it doesn't work as described in the docs**.
A workaround is to add pages one by one. This works for me:

```
spam = [PngImageFile('pil_red.png'), PngImageFile('pil_blue.png')]
print(spam)
# [<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=60x30 at 0x7F6B33A14128>, 
# <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=60x30 at 0x7F6B33A202E8>]


for img in spam:
    try:
        img.save('test.pdf', append=True)
    except FileNotFoundError: # if the file does not exists, save the first image
        img.save('test.pdf')
```

Would be interesting to find out why `append_images` does not work.

Actually, with `save_all=True` it works for me

```
from PIL.PngImagePlugin import PngImageFile
from PIL import Image
    
img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color = 'red')
img.save('pil_red.png')
img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color = 'blue')
img.save('pil_blue.png')

spam = [PngImageFile('pil_red.png'), PngImageFile('pil_blue.png')]
print(spam)
# [<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=60x30 at 0x7F6B33A14128>, 
# <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=60x30 at 0x7F6B33A202E8>]
spam[0].save('test.pdf', save_all=True, append_images=spam[1:])
```

Answer (score -3):

You cannot modify pdf like this. Pdf was created to represent physical paper with rigidly mapped contents. In fact Adobe invented the very digital paper standard and they made it strictly read only format.

Comment: This is is neither correct, nor does it answer the question.

Comment: I am familiar with the ISO standard, thank you, and I already agree that Adobe engineered it. What I was saying though is that is not correct that PDFs are read-only because they clearly can be written. Furthermore, this doesn't help OP write a PDF, which is what he was asking.

Comment: I actually kinda feel not great about giving solutions from fringe sections of the internet. Especially when the official document decided not to cover.